# Gradle multi-project configuration

Tags: java, gradle

I'm looking at migrating from ant to Gradle because we want to speed up builds by running projects in parallel and to simplify configuration, however it seems to me that these goals are mutually exclusive for Gradle builds. Hopefully I'm missing something.
So I'd like a nice example of a multi-project Gradle setup compiling 3 java projects such that A and B can be compiled in parallel and C depends on both. Also such that some properties can be configured (dynamically) and used in all three projects, perhaps configured in an additional root project.

Comment: By dynamically, I mean this kind of thing. A property is defined as `BuildArea` and contains a path, then another property is defined as `BuiltZips=${BuildArea}/zips`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by configuring properties "dynamically"? in general you should be able to get a parallel executed build for a project with three subprojects as you have described. I pushed a sample skeleton project setup at https://github.com/breskeby/gradle-snippets/tree/master/multiparallel

hope that helps,

cheers,
René

Comment: But in the Gradle manual:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
"coupling of projects effectively prevents Gradle from building multiple projects in parallel"
and
"A very common way for projects to be coupled is by using configuration injection. It may not be immediately apparent, but using key Gradle features like the allprojects and subprojects keywords automatically cause your projects to be coupled."

Comment: I have to doublecheck the wording in the gradle userguide and what it means in detail. but when running the sample project I linked above you can see that sub1:classes and sub2:classes are executed in parallel.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Do you know where I can file a documentation bug?

Comment: The best place to raise those issues is the gradle forum (http://forums.gradle.org)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example app I built a week or two ago that covers this usecase: https://github.com/jadekler/git-java-websiteskeleton. Check out the settings.gradle in particular, as well as the application package which bundles all the other components (an individual java app, each) into one.